# Troubleshooting Responsive Design Woes: Resolving Errors and Glitches for a Seamless User Experience

Tags: web, responsive-design, frontend, helper

[here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiU35.png) recently i had created a site as my portfolio but i am facing some difficulties in responsiveness  same code same site but different browser both has different output anyone how can i fix this ?

left one is Firefox and right one opera browser

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)